# How to automatically receive the PR status (title, opener, etc) once a new PR is opened in a specified repository?

Tags: python-3.x, github, github-api, pull-request

I have written a simple python script that can do:

- Retrieve the status (title, opener, url, assignee, open_date, labels, etc) of all open pull requests and issues in the GitHub repository that I'm working on.
- Write them into a Google spreadsheet. (for example, PRs go into sheet 1, and issues go into sheet 2)

But my problem is that I want to track the PRs at **real-time**, meaning that every time someone opens a pull request or an issue in the repo, my python script will be automatically run and update the sheets.

How can I do that? Is it possible to do that with python3?

---

I tried the Pull Reminders slack app, which can send me a slack reminder every time a PR is opened in the specified repository. But I'm not sure how they get the PR status at real-time.

Is there anything else like Pull Reminders that provides the related API service?

Comment: Read up on "web hooks".

Comment: There may be an easier solution if you described why you want to track them in a spreadsheet. That sounds slightly inefficient and redundant